# Calculating the derivative in terms of $y(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It has been a few years since I have taken calculus, and I must have forgotten how to do this. I need to find the derivative of the Sigmoid function in terms of $y(x)$. I have found [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html) which shows the answer is $y(1-y)$.

I know how to derive the final derivative using the derivative rules, but I don't know how to get  $y(1-y)$?

I need to find the derivative in this form for several functions to be used in back propogation of a neural network. This is [list of activation functions](http://www.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/statist/education/textbook/eng/glosa.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is
$$
y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}},
$$
and it has derivative
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\left(\frac{1+e^{-x}-1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)\\
&=y(1-y).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Tunk-Fey gave you a first answer. I shall give you another approach.

Since the sigmoid function is given by $$y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$ you can extract $x$ from the definition and get $$e^{-x}=\frac {1-y}{y}$$ or that is to say $$e^{x}=\frac {y}{1-y}$$ and $$x=\log \left(\frac {y}{1-y}\right)=\log(y)-\log(1-y)$$Then, by differentiation, $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac {1}{y}+\frac {1}{1-y}=\frac {1}{y(1-y)}$$ Taking the inverse of both sides leads to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1-y)$$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey. I think it is a minimum to aknowledge the fact that another participant gave a good answer ! Cheers.